# Get strings for some specific region

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to use the powershell code to get the string of some specific area

please see the picture below, the content of the green rectangle needs to be retained, and all other strings are deleted.

I added some substrings in the second area. They look more complicated. I want to know if I can extract the desired data at once.

Need to get the data:

--------[ abc不好 ]

[ c高速缓存 / L1-Cache ]

[ 内存阵列 / System Memory ]

--------[ 太好cde ]

[image]

```
--------[ 好吗 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    string1                                              description1
    string4                                          ---[ 太好了 ]----description4好

--------[ abc不好 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  [ a系统 ]

    系统:
      制造商                                            Intel Corporation
      产品                                              HuronRiver Platform


  [ 主板 ]

    主板:
      制造商                                            Intel Corp.
      产品                                              Emerald Lake
      版本                                              V1.24                                       

  [ c高速缓存 / L1-Cache ]

    高速缓存:
      类型                                              数据
      状态                                              已启用


  [ 高速缓存 / L2-Cache ]

    高速缓存:
      类型                                              数据
      状态                                              已启用

  [ d高速缓存 / L3-Cache ]

    高速缓存:
      类型                                              Unified
      状态                                              已启

  [ 内存阵列 / System Memory ]

    内存阵列:
      位置                                              主板
      内存阵列功能                                      系统内存

  [ 内存设备 / ChannelA-DIMM0 ]

    内存设备:
      形状特征                                          SODIMM
      类型                                              DDR3


--------[ cde好 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    好string1                                              description1
    string3                                              description3
    string4                                          ---[ 太好了 ]----description4好a


--------[ 太好cde ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    了string1                                              description1
    string3                                              description3
    string4                                          ---[ 太好了 ]----description4好b


--------[ hef好 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    好string1                                              description1
    string3                                              description3
    string4                                          ---[ 太好了 ]----description4好
```

Comment: What have you attempted? Your "question" reads more like a request.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea what to do with this problem. it can be solved by using powershell?

Comment: how do you determine what to keep? every even numbered block? blocks tagged with strings that start with `d` or `e`? [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming input is from a file, I'd

- `Get-Content file.txt -raw` and
- split into sections determined by the begin of the ruler line with a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- use `Where-Object` to filter by a unique word inside the section

---

```
$Unique = [regex]::Escape("[ abc")
(Get-Content .\file.txt -raw) -split '(?M)(?=^--------\[)' -ne '' |
    Where-Object { $PSItem -match $Unique}
```

Sample output:

```
--------[ abc不好 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    好string1                                              description1
    string2                                         description2
    好string3                                              description3
    string4                                          ---[ 太好了 ]----description4好2
```

**EDIT: adapted script for changed requirements**

```
$Unique = 'abc不好|太好cde|c高速缓存 \/ L1-Cache|内存阵列 \/ System Memory'
(Get-Content .\SU_56606905.txt -raw) -split '(?M)(?=(^--------\[|^  \[))'|
    Where-Object { $PSItem -match $Unique}
```

Sample output:

```
--------[ abc不好 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  [ c高速缓存 / L1-Cache ]

    高速缓存:
      类型                                              数据
      状态                                              已启用



  [ 内存阵列 / System Memory ]

    内存阵列:
      位置                                              主板
      内存阵列功能                                      系统内存


--------[ 太好cde ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    了string1                                              description1
    string3                                              description3
    string4                                          ---[ 太好了 ]----description4好b
```

Comment: The -match operator is regex based, use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) = OR `$Unique = '(\[ abc不好|\[ hef好)'` here without automatic escaping.

Comment: When using also an alternation for the split, yes. Drawback is that without a staged approach a section with sub-regions can*t be accessed as a whole. Try: `-split '(?M)(?=(^--------\[|^  \[))'`

Comment: See changed script.

Comment: I have encountered some problems. I made some changes to the above example. Now some fields are duplicates, such as Motherboard: In addition, I need to correctly replace the Engineer as Ultimate. After I try to add a field, I can't get the required value. can You help. me? thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, bit **NO**. If you have a new question,  **ask a new question** referencing it as a follow up to this one. This site presents solutions with Q&A. To follow the timeline a new reader would have to view all the edits you made to the original question what's quite tedious. I will do a rollback and please ask a *new* question and get the chance of a wider audience, I think ATM it's just me, recognizing the chnages you made.

Comment: Thanks for my reminder, I submitted a new question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711238/merge-texts-from-discontinuous-areas

Answer (score 4):

We can likely start with an expression that'd collect new lines:

```
.*(\[ ddf \]|\[ edf \])[\s\S]*?description4\s*
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/9MYqQm/1/)

```
.*(\[ ddf \]|\[ edf \])[\s\S]*?\s*(?<=--------\[)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/mLc2XG/1)

```
.*(\[ ddf \]|\[ edf \])[\s\S]*?\s*\n(?:-)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/mLc2XG/1)

If we'd have a fixed substring in description 4, we can simply use that, such as:

```
.*(\[ ddf \]|\[ edf \])[\s\S]*?---\[ \?\?\?\? \]----.+\s*
```

#### [Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/8s2aBy/1/)

```
.*(\[ .*abc.* \]|\[ .*cde \])[\s\S]*?\]----.+\s*
```

#### [Demo 5](https://regex101.com/r/bviV5g/1/)

---

#### Edit:

Since we have dynamic patterns and it would change based on our inputs, we'd be just using a single rule for each, by getting a non-repeating unique substring from the top left and a non-repeating unique substring from the bottom right, and we'd design our expression, then we'd connect them using logical ORs:

```
(.*(\[ .*系统概述.* \][\s\S]*?LapTop\s*)|(.*\[ AIDA64 Extreme \][\s\S]*?10:14\s*)|(.*\[ DMI \])[\s\S]*?HuronRiver CRB.+\s*)
```

#### [Demo 6](https://regex101.com/r/R5qnlZ/1)

```
(.*(\[ .*TOP LEFT.* \][\s\S]*?Bottom RIGHT.*\s*))|(.*(\[ .*TOP LEFT.* \][\s\S]*?Bottom RIGHT.*\s*))
```

#### [Demo 7](https://regex101.com/r/lfO9AW/1)

Comment: The ending characters （description4）are examples. Actually, the words at the end of each area are different.

Comment: After adding unicode characters, I can't match the results. I don't know regular expressions, the online expression tools, it looks good, I need to learn, my English is not very good.  2 and 4

Comment: Is the result I want! WOW! Your regular expression programming ability is too strong. If you don't mind, can you tell me how you learned regular expressions? Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Hello, I just used a piece of text to test, some of the results are included, some places have no content   https://regex101.com/r/bviV5g/2

Comment: In actual use, only the part of the title is fixed, E.g: 【系统概述、  AIDA64 Extreme 、
 DMI】and other contents are changed. E.g:【 10:14   、  LapTop  、 HuronRiver CRB Platform】

Comment: Still not successful, I need to extract the contents of the three headings below:
---AIDA64 Extreme---
---系统概述---
---DMI---