# Merge texts from discontinuous areas

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to delete the content in the red rectangle in picture 1, and then generate a new text file.

Also, replace AIDA64 Engineer with AIDA64 Ultimate

Because the reserved fields are divided into different areas, for example: **Motherboard:**, it seems to be somewhat difficult

In the following post, some related issues have been resolved.
[Get strings for some specific region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606905/get-strings-for-some-specific-region)

[image]

```
--------[ AIDA64 Engineer ]------------------------------------------------------------

    version                                              AIDA64 Engineer v6.00.5100/cn

--------[ System verview ]-------------------------------------------------------------

    Motherboard:
      Processor name                                    Mobile DualCore Intel

    DMI:
      DMI BIOS Vendor                                   Phoenix Technologies

--------[ DMI ]------------------------------------------------------------------------

  [ BIOS ]

    BIOS Attributes:
      Vendor                                            Phoenix Technologies Ltd.

  [ Motherboard ]

    Motherboard:
      manufacturer                                      Intel Corp.

    Motherboard manufacturer:
      company name                                      Intel Corporation

--------[ Overclocking ]---------------------------------------------------------------

    Motherboard:
      Motherboard ID                                     <DMI>

    BIOS Attributes:
      System BIOS date                                   12/24/2012

--------[ PCI/PnP Network ]------------------------------------------------------------

    Atheros AR5009 802.11a/g/n Wireless                   PCI
    Broadcom NetLink BCM57785 PCI-E                       PCI
```

Comment: What do the items in the red boxes have in common besides that they have to be deleted ?

Comment: At present, I have not found a solution to the problem, and there are not many rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the strings to remove seem to have nothing in common, this long regex replace might help:

```
$re = '\s+(DMI:\s+DMI BIOS Vendor|Motherboard manufacturer:\s+company name|BIOS Attributes:\s+System BIOS date)[^-]+'
$nlnl = ([Environment]::NewLine * 2)  # replace with two newlines
(Get-Content -Path 'PATH TO THE FILE' -Raw) -replace $re, $nlnl -replace 'AIDA64 Engineer', 'AIDA64 Ultimate'
```

Result:

> ```
> --------[ AIDA64 Ultimate ]------------------------------------------------------------
>
>     version                                              AIDA64 Ultimate v6.00.5100/cn
>
> --------[ System verview ]-------------------------------------------------------------
>
>     Motherboard:
>       Processor name                                    Mobile DualCore Intel
>
> --------[ DMI ]------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>   [ BIOS ]
>
>     BIOS Attributes:
>       Vendor                                            Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
>
>   [ Motherboard ]
>
>     Motherboard:
>       manufacturer                                      Intel Corp.
>
> --------[ Overclocking ]---------------------------------------------------------------
>
>     Motherboard:
>       Motherboard ID                                     <DMI>
>
> --------[ PCI/PnP Network ]------------------------------------------------------------
>
>     Atheros AR5009 802.11a/g/n Wireless                   PCI
>     Broadcom NetLink BCM57785 PCI-E                       PCI
> ```

---

**Edit**

If you only want to replace `AIDA64 Engineer` in the header and not also in the text later on, change this part:

```
-replace 'AIDA64 Engineer', 'AIDA64 Ultimate'
```

into

```
-replace '\[ AIDA64 Engineer \]', '[ AIDA64 Ultimate ]'
```

Comment: -replace 'AIDA64 Engineer', 'AIDA64 Ultimate'  This expression has a problem because I only want to replace the fields in the first header.

Comment: @tianyi I have edited the code to do just that. Please have a look.